# Can we setup HTTP caching in a SOCKS proxy?

Tags: http, caching, networking, proxy, socks

I know that , Socks proxy accepts every type of requests like smtp, dns etc.- whereas http proxy accepts only http requests. With the help of this we can do http caching in the http proxy easily.

Can http caching be done in a socks proxy?